# Equivalent of a data-binary upload using cURL in RestSharp

Tags: c#, rest, csv, curl, restsharp

A REST API has a method for uploading the contents of a .csv file. In response, it gives us an `Id` with which we can can track our upload. I have a *cURL* version of the request and I want to have a *RestSharp* version of it.

**cURL:**

```
https://api.mailjet.com/v3/DATA/contactslist/$listID/CSVData/text:plain \
-H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
--data-binary "@./test.csv"
```

What the API has not mentioned is that, should there necessarily be a file called `test.csv` or can I just upload the raw content of the file like this?

```
"email","age"
"foo@example.org",42
"bar@example.com",13
"sam@ple.co.uk",37
```

So, if we have the value of `$listID` and we want to send the above content to the API how can I attach the `binary-data` to my request using *RestSharp*?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39039326/1097429