# Translate cUrl to restsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, curl, restsharp

I have a cUrl request:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/zip" --data-binary @C:\nyc_khr.zip  http://localhost:9090/geoserver/rest/workspaces/nyc_roads/datastores/roads/file.shp
```

I need make a request like above, but using C#
Example of my code:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(URL)
{
      Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("admin", "geoserver")
};

var data = File.ReadAllBytes(somePath);


string url = @"rest/workspaces/nyc_roads/datastores/roads/finalas.shx";
var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.PUT);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");

request.AddFile("finalik.zip", data, "finalik.zip", "application/zip");
var response = client.Execute(request);
var res = response.ContentType;
```

Comment: What problem / error do you have?

Comment: I got from server "Could not determine format. Try setting the Content-type header".  But if I use cUrl it works fine. \

Comment: In your example I see that URLs don't match - cURL points to `roads/file.shp`, but RestSharp points to `roads/finalas.shx`. Could this be the reason, or is this just some example code?

Comment: It is not important for this situation. The problem: I don't know how to correctly attach file to request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
request.AddFile()
```

this worked for me:

```
request.Parameters.Clear();
request.AddParameter("application/zip", data, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```